# Is a binary probit model which predicts the outcome of every observation to be true still useful for analysing effects of explanatory variables?

Tags: regression, model, binary-data, predictor, probit

So I have a binary probit model for labour participation restricted to a specific age group and region. The remaining explanatory variables include sex, education, and having dependent children (all binary variables) and their interactions.

Now here's the issue. Whilst most of the terms are significant, the models I have built on the data have either predicted labour participation to be true (coded 1) for everyone or in some models, the number of observations predicted to be false (coded 0) is very low - much lower than the true observed number.

That said over 80% of observations are still categorised correctly - and I presume this is because for any given combination of variables, the probability of labour participation is above 50%, hence it's predicted to be true more or less all the time.

Is this an issue? There's clearly other variables not included in the dataset which affect probability of participation. But if the aim is not to predict whether someone will participate or not, but rather analyse the effect of the given variables on the probability of participation, is the model sufficient to make such comments on it?

Side question - what is the term used to describe the accuracy of negative observations? There's recall and precision, but they are both measures of the accuracy of true predictions.